# GAS: setFormula ) missing after argument list

Tags: google-apps-script, excel-formula

I have the following line in GAS but it breaks when I use `""`, instead of `0` in the `IFERROR` part of the formula.

```
cell.setFormula("=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(K2:K,UPS!B:D,3,FALSE),""))");
```

It returns: `Missing ) after argument list`

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use either one to fix this:

```
  cell.setFormula('=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(K2:K,UPS!B:D,3,FALSE),""))');
  cell.setFormula("=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(K2:K,UPS!B:D,3,FALSE),\"\"))");
```

The problem arises because you have "(double quotation marks)" in your code. Its special character hence needs to be escaped using '\' like so '\"' or you enter your entire string within single quotas '"string here"'

Comment: Considering you were asking questions about writing GAS 16hrs ago and you already made a working code. I believe you will be explaining others soon enough :)